# Twitter Bootstrap tabs not working within a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In a rails application, I'm loading the contents of a modal window (bootstrap modal) through Ajax. This works fine.

This content contains tabs (bootstrap tabs). The tabs are displayed properly, I can click on the tabs and the active tab will change properly... but the content will not change.

```
<div id="negotiation-details">
  <div id="negotiation-overview"></div>

  <ul id="nego-tabs-menu" class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#nego-figures">Figures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nego-dates">Dates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nego-characteristics">Characteristics</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div id="nego-figures" class="tab-pane active">figures content</div>
    <div id="nego-dates" class="tab-pane">dates content</div>
    <div id="nego-characteristics" class="tab-pane">characteristics content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have an idea?
can it be caused by the fact that the tabs are loaded after DOM? If so, how can I enable them again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake. It turns out I had a second modal window rendered.

My javascript updated the content of the modal based on the class name. By targeting the modal with the right id fixed things.

```
$('#modal-window .modal-body')
```

instead of

```
$('.modal-body')
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and it worked after adding a

```
"data-toggle"=>"tab"
```

to each of the tabs menu items, like so:

```
#negotiation-details
  #negotiation-overview
  %ul#nego-tabs-menu.tabs
    %li.active
      %a{:href => "#nego-figures","data-toggle"=>"tab"} Figures
    %li
      %a{:href => "#nego-dates","data-toggle"=>"tab"} Dates
    %li
      %a{:href => "#nego-characteristics","data-toggle"=>"tab"} Characteristics
  #my-tab-content.tab-content
    #nego-figures.tab-pane.active figures content
    #nego-dates.tab-pane dates content
    #nego-characteristics.tab-pane characteristics content
```

Ps. Sorry about the haml syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but doesn't work within the modal (although it works if rendered through a "normal" action). So the problem really seems to be when rendering the code as the result of an Ajax call. Still looking. And Merry Christmas!